# Getting a data-attribute with DomCrawler

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

Is it possible to get the data with DomCrawler?

`$cralwer->attr('class')` gets me the node's class attribute, but `->attr('data-something')` or `->attr('something')` always results in `null`.

Edit: tagging PHP also because I tried while manipulating the `DomElement` object from php (using `->attributes->getNamedItem()`) and it still won't work. I'm wondering if it's just not possible to return a data attribute at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. The data attribute in the source code was written as such : `data-SomeAttribute`.

Trying to access it with the cases (`$crawler->attr('data-SomeAttribute'`) is what is failing here. Doing it without the case (`$crawler->attr('data-someattribute'`) works perfectly fine!